# Enable launch as admin adding a manifest file in the installation path

Tags: c#, manifest, uac

I have an application that runs fine as a standard user. 
I want to be able to do the following: when I copy a manifest file (I don't want to embed it as otherwise the application will always run as admin) to the installation folder, the application should always start as admin.

Here's the text I've inserted in a file called myappname.exe.manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

I expected it was enough to copy it into the installation folder to have the application automatically start as admin but it's not working as expected.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you embedded default manifest file which on Windows Server 2003+ overrides external manifest (up to Windows XP the external manifest overrides the internal one). To fix this you can build the application without manifest file (Project properties/Application/Manifest -> Create application without a manifest). Also remember the correct naming of the manifest file which is MyAppName.exe.manifest